# Multiple title pages in Bearmer

Tags: beamer

I will give a talk that combines 2 independent topics. So the very first frame is going to be the usual `\titlepage`. But I want to have two other frames with a very similar layout introducing each topic. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `beamer` you can use `\titlepage` and `\title`, `\author`, `\institute` (and other titling commands) as many times as you wish. Then you can produce the main titlepage and the two subsidiary ones, perhaps introducing some changes to the color/fonts of the corresponding elements:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\newcommand\SecondaryTitleOPtions{
  \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=structure!40}
  \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=structure}
  \setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=structure}
  \setbeamercolor{date}{fg=structure}
}

\title{The General Title}
\subtitle{The general subtitle}
\author{The General Authors}
\institute{The General Institute}
\date{August 23, 2048}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\SecondaryTitleOPtions

\title{The First Topic}
\subtitle{The subtitle for this topic}
\author{Some Authors}
\institute{The Institute One}
\date{}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\SecondaryTitleOPtions
\title{The Second Topic}
\subtitle{The subtitle for this topic}
\author{Some Other Authors}
\institute{The Institute Two}
\date{}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've used `\date` to add some extra info supposed to show only on the first frame. But it repeats on every other titlepage.

Comment: @capadocia Please see my updated answer. For your requirement, use `\date{}` for the other titlepages.